# PDFBox how to create an accessible tagged PDF

Tags: java, accessibility, pdfbox

I am looking for an example that will show me how to create an **accessible** PDF for people using asistive technologies such as screen readers with **Apache PDFBox**. Upon looking at the API, I can see that there are classes available to add structure to the document however there is no clear example showing it's implementation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on this?? Anyone?

Comment: See newer question [Tagged PDF with PDFBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39872854/6002174).